# App is crashing on some devices. Android studio shows out of memory exception error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory, exoplayer

I am creating a music player app. I have three activities that have recycler views in it. I am loading music from server using exoplayer. I am loading like 10-20 images of 20kb size into recycler views using glide. My app is crashing in some phones with low memory. Android profiler shows that my app is consuming too much memory (screenshot below) App is running very smoothly in high-end phones. Can someone please tell me how to solve this memory issue so that app will run smoothly in all phones.

I have already added heaplarge=true in manifest

[image]

[image]

[image: Android Studio Profiler]

Comment: show us your build.gradle(module app)

Comment: change your targetSDKVersion to 23. This was my solution when I faced such situation.

Comment: convert your image to bitmap and then use it

Comment: @WaleedAsim I have attached the screenshots of gradle.

Comment: we don't want screenshots. [ask]

Comment: It works well and does not give this exception at all with the higher sdk models?

Comment: Yes, when i am running on a one-plus 5 its runs very smoothly. Maybe because it has enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your build.gradle in android section

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }
```

and add this in default config section

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

finally add dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have the `Memory leak` in your app.

1. you can try to use `leakCanary` to help you find some `Activity leak`.

   [link-to-github leakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)
2. Also you can use link to Analyze your code 
   [analyze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FovBS.png)
3. try android StrictMode, it can help you improve your code 
   [Strict Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways to resolved Out of memory error in Android.

1. [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

> Understand properly how to handle large bitmap with best practice in
>   android application

2. [Use TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/)

> TinyPNG uses smart lossy compression techniques to reduce the file
>   size of your PNG files. By selectively decreasing the number of colors
>   in the image, fewer bytes are required to store the data. The effect
>   is nearly invisible but it makes a very large difference in file size!

Compress all images using this link.

Reduce the size of all picture before use in your Android applications.

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score -1):

> Try adding `android:largeHeap="true"`
>       You can use this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to load large files but if you are adding huge amount of data then you can use
>   `multidex` as stated by other users

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```